# Why is the constant of integration independent of $x$?

Tags: calculus

Source video: [BlackpenRedpen video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5g6NFonKKU)

---

In this video from a fairly popular channel on youtube, he proves that if $f(x)$ is continuous, then:

$$ \int_{0}^{x} \int_{0}^{u} f(t)\,dt\,du = \int_0^x f(u)(x-u)du $$

by differentiating both sides with respect to $x$ and showing that $\frac{d}{dx}LHS = \frac{d}{dx}RHS$. Thus:

$$ \int_{0}^{x} \int_{0}^{u} f(t)\,dt\,du = \int_0^x f(u)(x-u)du + C $$

He shows that $C = 0$ by setting $x = 0$. I was confused about that and I saw a youtube comment that said:

> Btw, when you show that C = 0, isn't that result only true for x = 0? what about other x values?﻿

A reply said:

> You know, since the derivatives are equal, that left hand side and right hand side differ only by a single constant. This constant is the same independent of x. Therefore it suffices to show that the difference of l.h.s and r.h.s. is 0 for any one x to show that said constant (the difference of the two functions) is 0 and the functions are the same. x=0 is the canonical choice here.﻿

---

My question is why is $C$ independent of $x$?

Comment: $f'(x) = g'(x) \implies f(x) = g(x) + C(x)$ carries absolutely no information. i.e. without $f'(x)=g'(x)$, $f(x) = g(x) + C(x)$ is true by letting $C(x) = f(x)-g(x)$.

Comment: @Atbey The video doesn't make a ton of sense; I'm just as confused as how you can use that as a valid argument. Does this argument work as a proof?

Comment: As there are no indefinite integrals to begin with, thee are no constants of integration

Comment: @NeevParikh No, it is a comment only. I just want to emphasize that if you take $C$ to be an arbitrary function of $x$, then what it only says is difference of functions is again a function. But this does not explain why first $\implies$ holds for constant $C$.

Comment: If you have two differentiable functions $g $ and $ f$ such that $ f'(x) = g'(x) $, for every x, then the tow functions only differ by a constant. So we can rewrite $ g(x) = f(x) + C $ for some unknown constant $ C $. Now if you are given $ f(0) = g(0) $, we can find that $ C = 0 $ and therefor $ f(x) = g(x) $ for every x. just plug in $ LHS = f(x) $, $ RHS = g(x) $ and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the definition of the concept of primitive. A function $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is called a primitive of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ if $F' = f$. If we note that $F' = f$ implies $(F + constant)' = f$ and *vice versa*, if we identify the same class of primitives of $f$ as the "same" one (modulo constants, of course), and if we write $\int f$ for a generic primitive of $f$, then what the fundamental theorem of calculus asserts is the existence of primitive: under suitable conditions, the indefinite integral $x \mapsto \int_{a}^{x}f$ is a primitive of $f$. Also note that $f$ is a primitive of $f'$ trivially.

With the above in mind, let us analyze the puzzle. Suppose $f' = g'$. Then by definition they have the "same" primitive $f + C_{1} = g + C_{2}$, so $f=g + C_{2}-C_{1}$. Here we see that $C_{2}-C_{1}$ is a constant independent of the choice of the arguments of $f$ and $g$.

Note: Please be noted that this answer addresses the OP's question about the why the constant of integration is "constant", not the argument quoted by OP, which is not asked.

Comment: I'm slightly confused. By the 'same' primitive do you mean all primitives of the form $F + C$?

Comment: Yep, sure. And that is what "modulo constants" implies!

Comment: I didn't understand that term, sorry! Okay, so if you have a "class" of primitives, $F + C$, are you saying that both $f+C_1$ and $g + C_2$ belong to the same "class"?

Comment: Also just curious, is what the video did a valid argument?

Comment: For the class thing, pretty much there, yes. Some people even define $\int f$ as that class instead of a function. Don't worry about this distinction too much at this stage :). No I do not have time to examine a claim.

Comment: Then it makes sense, thanks. And no problem on the argument thing, that was just a curiosity.